# Strange marking on component

Tags: identification

I’m doing a repair on a radio and trying to source this component for replacement. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the service manual with schematics and part list? How do you know the part is broken? Even if it is broken, how do you know the new part won't also get broken if the problem is elsewhere?

Comment: The component that’s broken has 2 legs broken off and difficult to re solder.  No schematics unfortunately.

Comment: Which component on the board are you talking about?

Comment: The 6 pin one with the 24 on it.

Comment: The make, model and year of manufacture for the radio would probably go a long way here...

Comment: The radio in question is a Unication G3